# jQuery Mobile's changePage How to load a jQuery Collection in an other page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Here's the structure of my app: I have two HTML files:

- index.html
- items.html

items.html contains different data-role="page" divs.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="myitem" data-title = "Items1"> 
...
 </div>
```

In my page "index.html", I would like to do a changePage to a specific page located in items.html ( with something that would look like $.mobile.changePage('items.html#myitem')

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing single-page and multi-page templates is [not supported](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/why-is-only-the-first-page-loaded.html). You either have to put everything in one file, or to split everything in multiple files.